# How do I drag the entire Unity3d Windows/Mac application?

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine, screen, positioning

How would one go about causing the primary real estate of a Unity3d application, other than the clickable buttons, to act similarly to the title bar?  Specifically, I would like a user to be able to click and drag on the application screen to reposition it on their desktop.

Comment: Unity has no built-in support for that. It's theoretically possible with a native plugin, but it wouldn't be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain (from previous experience) that if I interpreted your question right, that ALL applications on Windows, and I think Mac will automatically have the ability to move the position via the title bar. It's just something all applications do unless told otherwise. Of course I may be completely wrong and Unity goes to auto fullscreen, or something, but chances are that you can drag it by the title bar.

Comment: Yes, the application has a functional title bar in both environments, but I'm wondering if I can make, at least part of, the rest of the application window behave the same way.  So, if I click and drag in the center of the application window, it will drag the entire window on the desktop screen.